# problema asignar permisos al rol SPATIE LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, users-roles, packages

Hola buenas tengo un problema con lo mencionado en la pregunta, explico:

-al crear un nuevo rol y asignarle sus permisos, estos no se declaran en la base de datos, como se muestran en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SE SUPONE QUE ESE ROL SE CREO CON ID 5 pero no aparece la id en la tabla de relacion Roles_Has_permissions

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SOLO APARECE DE LA ID 1 - 4 (Las cuales estaban creadas en la migracion)
ADJUNTO CODIGO DEL CONTROLLER

```js
public
function store(Request $request) {

  $roles = new Role();
  $roles - > name = $request - > nombre;
  $roles - > guard_name = $request - > guard_name;

  $permissions = $request['permiso']; 
  $roles - > save();

  if (is_array($permissions) || is_object($permissions)) {
    foreach($permissions as $permission) {
      $p = Permission::where('id', '=', $permission) - > firstOrFail();
      $roles = Role::where('name', '=', $name) - > first();
      $roles - > givePermissionTo($p);
    }
  }

  $message = array(
    'message' => 'Alumno creado con éxito',
    'type' => 'success'
  );
  return redirect() - > back() - > with($message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

**Primero:**
Qué es ese *espacio* en `- >`?

**Segundo:**
Estás creando un nuevo rol, se lo asignás a la variable `$roles` y después en vez de utilizar esa variable querés buscar el rol creado en la DB. No hace falta porque ya lo tenés en `$roles`, por otro lado, estás usando `$name` en el `where()` pero nunca definiste esa variable.

**Tercero:**
No hace falta que busques cada permiso por su ID en la DB. Por un lado porque `givePermissonTo()` soporta los ID directamente, y por otro lado porque existe el método `syncPermissions()` al que le podes pasar directamente un array con los IDs.

---

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $roles = new Role();
    $roles->name = $request->nombre;
    $roles->guard_name = $request->guard_name;

    $roles->save();
    $roles->syncPermissions($request->input('permiso', [])); // Si no hay ninguno pasa un array vacío

    $message = array(
        'message' => 'Alumno creado con éxito',
        'type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->back()->with($message);
}
```

[Documentación](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/basic-usage/)

Comment: Gracias amigo me aclaraste unas cosas que no sabia o simplemente las ignoraba, aplique tu código el syncPermissions, ahora me inserta mas o menos bien, ya que he seleccionado mas de un checkbox, pero solo me envía 1 solo checkbox :c si fueras tan amable de ayudarme con eso por favor @azeós

Comment: el tema de los espacios que se ve en los ' - > ' es problema de stack, ya que le puse ordenar codigo, y en vez de organizar lo desorganizo xD

Comment: ya lo solucione, lo que sucedía es que en el input de mi blade, necesitaba colococar el campo name="permiso[ ]" y yo lo tenia como: name="permiso" entonces por eso me enviaba solo 1 valor, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Excelente, me alegro. Para futuro, a mi al menos me resulta cómodo nombrar las variables en singular cuando se trata de un solo elemento (`$rol` en este caso) y en plural cuando son varios (`permisos[]`).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Role::create(['name' => $request->rol])->syncPermissions([$request->permisos]);
        return redirect('roles')->with('agregado','ok');
    }
```

te resultará mas fácil

Comment: lo que hace el codigo es que primero crea el rol luego al haberlo creado le asignan los permisos que se le han asignado